# Debian 10 systemd, how to disable autostart of graphical environments

Tags: debian, systemd

I installed a graphical environment on a server and I have decided that I no longer want to run that environment at boot. How can I disable it with systemd?

This is gnome desktop environment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

your current runlevel target is `graphical.target`

```
systemctl get-default 

graphical.target
```

It can be changed to boot to `multi-user.target` target

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

If you want to switch the target while system running

```
systemctl isolate graphical.target
```