# how to disable gdm and graphical interface on RHEL 8.2

Tags: rhel, gdm

I've tried `systemctl disable graphical.target` and didn't work. inittab says exactly "ADDING CONFIGURATION HERE WILL HAVE NO EFFECT ON YOUR SYSTEM."

Comment: You want to change the default target, not disable. Try `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debian 10 systemd, how to disable autostart of graphical environments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593111/debian-10-systemd-how-to-disable-autostart-of-graphical-environments)

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by @jordanm, and reinforced by RHEL support (thanks to Joe W. for a prompt response) we can disable via:

```
  # systemctl set-default multi-user.target
  # systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

> You need to have all active graphical sessions logged out prior to running 'systemctl isolate multi-user.target'

to re-enable:

```
  # systemctl isolate graphical.target
  # systemctl set-default graphical.target #it'll setup the gdm boot startup
  $ startx
```