# Debian does not start with a graphical interface

Tags: debian, boot, graphics, startx, runlevel

I'm using Debian Buster and it starts in text mode so that for me to run the graphical interface I always have to run `# startx` on the command line. How do I start it directly in graphical mode?

I saw in other questions that you have to edit the `/etc/inittab` file and change the run level to start in graphical mode, but apparently there is no such file or at least I didn't find it.

Can you help me?

Comment: I have explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593114/254422

Answer (score 3):

Please execute `tasksel` and select one of the several DM (display managers).

The job of an DM is to give a graphical screen to log in users, and, naturally, start X for that (already identified) user. [Example for a Gnome Debian system](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.after-first-boot.html).

To install a DM, debian supply a very simple (but critical) command line tool:

```
tasksel
```

If you select a version in the given list of Desktop Managers (not the same as a display manager, even if the same first two letters), the corresponding DM will be installed.

[image]

After you get several Desktop Managers installed, it could be that you want to select a diferent Display Manager even keeping the same Desktop Manager in use, because the log in screen is better for some reason. To change the default Display-Manager, execute:

```
dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

for the present display-manager in use.

[List of available Disply Managers in Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install your display manager. There are many options and you may want to try a couple before settling on one. lightdm is quite popular, however because I usually use a Gnome desktop I'll suggest gdm3. These instructions remain the same for any of the display managers though.

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
```

You can then set the default display manager by editing /etc/X11/default-display-manager

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

If it doesn't show the single line listed below, manually enter it.

> /usr/sbin/gdm3

Now reboot your machine

```
sudo systemctl reboot
```

Comment: Why gdm3, why not lxde or kde or mate or any other? This answer is too restrictive and assumes what the user should use.

Comment: I edited/updated my answer in response to this comment ^ (providing more diversity in display manager options)

Comment: gdm3 isnt a desktop environment, but a window manager, this is a workaround rather than a solution, but it may still serve the purpose of getting you into a graphical session/ desktop environment,what ever that might be. (gnome, mate, lxde, xfce, kde-plasma etc..)